# error : "object" was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, codeblocks

Can someone please tell me why I'm getting this error?
error : firstpokemon was not declared in this scope.
And is there another way to write it?

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Charmender.h"
#include "Bulbasaur.h"
#include "Game.h"
#include "Squirtle.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
 srand(time(0));
 Game game;
 int frstchoice = game.getstarterchoice();
    if(frstchoice == 1)
        Charmender firstpokemon;
    else if(frstchoice == 2)
        Bulbasaur firstpokemon;
    else if(frstchoice == 3)
        Squirtle firstpokemon;

cout << "You chose No." << frstchoice << endl;
cout << firstpokemon.getatk();
    return 0;
}
```

The error is at cout << firstpokemon.getatk();

Comment: Unrelated to your current problem, but what if `frstchoice` is *not* one of the alternatives you check for?

Answer (score 4):

You have three separate variables called `firstpokemon`, each scoped within the branch of the `if...else` statement in which it's declared. They are not in the wider scope of `main`.

A variable can only have a single type. If you want a variable to refer to various polymorphic types (assuming a common base class), then you'll need a pointer or reference, and you'll typically need dynamic allocation:

```
std::unique_ptr<Pokemon> firstpokemon;
if(frstchoice == 1)
    firstpokemon.reset(new Charmender);
else if(frstchoice == 2)
    firstpokemon.reset(new Bulbasaur);
else if(frstchoice == 3)
    firstpokemon.reset(new Squirtle);

if (firstpokemon)
    cout << firstpokemon->getatk();
else
    cout << "Wrong choice\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

Code inside `if` statements are in their own scoping block, so they are local inside that block only.

If your classes are inheriting from the same base class then you can use a pointer to the base class, and allocate the instances inside the `if` statements.

Answer (score 0):

Your `firstpokemon` is a local variable as it is getting created within the `if` block.
Being a local variable , you **CANNOT** use it in any other block , and hence when you try to `cout<<firstpokemon;` in the main function , the compiler flags an error as it is unknown to the compiler at that point in time.